# "As was his habit" what does it mean?

Tags: grammar, expressions, syntactic-analysis

"As was his habit, he planned to spend the month of August in Normandy, visiting friends and working on his house."

I often see this kind of structure:As was his habit. But I do not understand what it means.

Please explain the structure and meaning.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This might be better on english learners (ell.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "His habit was to spend August in Normandy.  Because he was in this habit, his plans for next August were the same."

"As was his habit" is a little bit formal, and possibly even archaic - the more modern version would be "Customarily, he would..." or "He was accustomed to ..." but "As was his habit" is very understandable and used.

A [habit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habit) is any action that is done repeatedly and routinely - e.g., Smoking cigarettes is a bad habit.  or My habit is to exercise 3 times a ... {week | month | year }

Comment: Thank you so much. Your example about smoking is very timely as I have just smoked my hopefully last cigarette.

Answer (score 1):

"As is/was his habit" to me bears the same connotation as "as is/was usual"

How about the following adv's:

Habitually/customarily, he planned to spend the month of August in Normandy, visiting friends and working on his house."